# Why aren't immutable Map concrete classes defined as case classes?

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching

What about any case where someone want to apply pattern matching on an entire `Map` object?

Example (though not compiling) would be:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) //scala.collection.immutable.Map2
    m match {
      case Map2("a",1,"b",2)  => println("matched")   //conceptual code line 
      case _ => println("not matched")
    }
}
```

What are possible reasons preventing the `Map2` definition as a case class?

- Case class preventing encapsulation of internal fields? (like `key1` and `value1`...)
- Case class doesn't apply with generics type parameters?
- Rare usage of matching an entire Map (making often non-sense)?

Comment: Because Map is unordered by default, thus your pattern matching might occasionally fail with no visible reason: say you're looking for Map2("a"->1,"b"->2) whereas map will be ordered as Map("b"->2,"a"->1).

Comment: I actually found one way to implement this, but solution is a little bit crazy. Just look at section "Parameterizable Extractors": http://hacking-scala.posterous.com/introduction-to-type-dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One salient reason is that deriving new classes from case classes is deprecated at best, dangerous at worst. In order to allow users (or Scala standard library authors) to derive from these classes, they may not be case classes.